# Fatal error while trying to call a method in constructor

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to write my own MVC Framework [using this tutorial](http://anantgarg.com/2009/03/13/write-your-own-php-mvc-framework-part-1/). Everything worked fine and i completed the tutorial with no issues.

However later i decided to use PDO (PHP Data objects) instead of mysql() functions for Database Operations. So i modified My sqlQuery.php file to use PDO istead of mysql functions.

**sqlQuery.php**

```
<?php


class SQLQuery {
    private $_dbHandle;
    private $_result;

    /**
     * Connects to database
     *
     * @param $address
     * @param $account
     * @param $pwd
     * @param $name
     */

    function connect($address, $account, $pwd, $name) {
        try{
            $this->_dbHandle = new PDO("mysql:host=$address;dbname=$name", $account, $pwd);
        }catch (PDOException $e) {
            die($e->getCode() . " : " . $e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    /** Disconnects from database **/

    function disconnect() {
        $this->_dbHandle = null;
    }

    function get($whereClause = array()) {
        $query = "select * from $this->_table";
        if(is_array($whereClause) && count($whereClause)){
            $query .= " where ";
            foreach($whereClause as $column=>$value)
                $query .= " $column  = $value";
        }else if(is_int($whereClause)){
            $query .= " where id = $whereClause ";
        }
        return $this->query($query);
    }


    /**
     * Custom SQL Query
     *
     * @param $query
     * @return array|bool
     */

    function query($query) {
        $this->_result = $this->_dbHandle->query($query);
        $this->_result->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, $this->_model);

        if (preg_match("/select/i",$query)) {
            $result = array();
            $numOfFields = $this->_result->rowCount();
            if($numOfFields > 1){
                while($result[] = $this->_result->fetch()){

                }
            }else{
                $result = $this->_result->fetch();
            }
            return $result;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Now when In my Controller when i print `$this->Item->get()` I get all the results in my database as Objects of Items Model and `$this->Item->get(2)` gives me the item object with id=2 as expected.

However, I don't like the idea that my API needs to be to call an additional method get() to get the objects of the Items Model, Instead it makes more sense that when a Items Model is initialized i get the desired object and so my API can be `$this->item->mycolumnName`.

To achieve this i tried to move the `get()` call in the Models constructor like this :

**model.php**

```
<?php

class Model extends SQLQuery{

    protected $_model;

    function __construct() {

        $this->connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME);
        $this->_model = get_class($this);
        $this->_table = strtolower($this->_model)."s";
        $this->get();
    }

    function __destruct() {
    }

}
```

However this gives me a Fatal error

```
 Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '256' reached, aborting! in /var/www/html/FitternityAssignment/library/sqlquery.php on line 59
```

I don't know what i have done wrong.

Comment: Which line is line 59 in `sqlquery.php`?

Comment: `$this->_result = $this->_dbHandle->query($query);`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is line 59: `while($result[] = $this->_result->fetch()){`

```
function query($query) {
    $this->_result = $this->_dbHandle->query($query);
    $this->_result->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, $this->_model);

    if (preg_match("/select/i",$query)) {
        $result = array();
        $numOfFields = $this->_result->rowCount();
        if($numOfFields > 1){
            while($result[] = $this->_result->fetch()){

            }
        }else{
            $result = $this->_result->fetch();
        }
        return $result;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Let's narrow in on the issue:

```
while($result[] = $this->_result->fetch()){

}
```

Infinite loop.

When `fetch()` returns something, then it is **added** to `$result`, because `$result` is an array, and then of course it evaluates to true because the size of `$result` grows each time a fetched result is added.

```
$results = [];
while($row = $this->_result->fetch()){
    $results[] = $row; // or whatever you need to do with the row
}
```

Might work. I say might because it depends on what `$this->_result->fetch()` returns when no results are left. I'll assume false or null, in which case the above will work, because when there are no more results then `fetch()` will return null or false and `$row` will then evaluate to false.